# How to make "amplify add function" with python boto3 or step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Amplify application and I need to add a Lambda function to my Backend Environment.

Manually, in the AWS CLI, I can type `amplify add function`, but I need to do this with the boto3 (Python) SDK or with an AWS Step Function to add the Lambda Function with code.

What is the way to do that?